# profile.LdapProfile, error while reading canonicalDN

Tags: password-management, freeipa

[PWM](https://github.com/pwm-project/pwm) is logging the following error, when connected to my FreeIPA server.

> ERROR, profile.LdapProfile, error while reading canonicalDN for dn
>   value 'uid=pwmproxy,cn=sysaccounts,cn=etc,dc=example,dc=com', error:
>   search for canonical DN resulted in no results

What is a canonical DN? What is its equivalent in FreeIPA? Is it okay to ignore the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most LDAP servers generate a virtual attribute on each entry indicating that entry's DN. This can be used in filters (unlike `dn` which isn't an attribute), and to discover the real DN of an entry being viewed through *aliases* (the equivalent of resolving a symlink).

In other LDAP servers, this attribute is called:

- 389ds (FreeIPA): `entryDN`
- ActiveDirectory: `distinguishedName`
- OpenLDAP: `entryDN`

Comment: You need to enable it in your LDAP browser. Right-click the entry and choose "Fetch operational attributes".

Comment: I just found out that I have to enable operational attributes, and deleted the comment. I didn't know that you had already replied. Sorry.